# What is the difference between the `{}` type and the `object` type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

what is the difference between:

```
function foo(x: {}) {}
```

and

```
function foo(x: object) {}` in TypeScript?
```

I can't find a case where the two are different. For example, even though `null` is an Object (with a capital 'O'), neither line of the following type-checks:

```
const x: {} = null`;
const y: object = null`;
```

Comment: You need to read [the documentation on `object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object). It is defined by TypeScript to be any non-primitive. `null` is a primitive.

Comment: Anything is compatible with `{}` including primitives, `object` represents only non primitives